# getting very large value in loss and val_loss

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, regression, google-colaboratory

I did a regression problem in that val_loss is very high nearly 5000 and loss is nearly 1100.
I normalized the input data. Also used early callback function.

```
      model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

  model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
```

and this is the output
[te](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTblm.png)

I tried 3000 epochs. It increased the val_loss after some point

this is history 
[history image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYM3M.png)

[MAE vs epochs plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NruRu.png)

[MSE vs epochs plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtzBp.png)

Comment: You have a model which is clearly learning (validation losses decreasing per epoch), and with a final validation MAE of ~ 38. It looks like this can be further reduced with further training. It's not clear what exactly you ask about here - the standard answer would be *continue training*...

Comment: I increased the patience value in-order to increase training. But val_loss and val_mae values are increasing

Comment: Why don't you try increasing the number of epochs to `3000` or something like that? and please attach a graph showing the loss vs no. of epochs...

Comment: I tried it and attached the results in my post @desertnaut